# colon in sass, not sure how to reference in HTML

Tags: html, css, sass

The code below is not applying the CSS rule `clearfix: after` I have never used a CSS rule with a colon in the middle so I don't know why it is not working, any help.

I have the following code in my SCSS file

```css
.clearfix { zoom: 1;}
.clearfix:before, .clearfix:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
}
.clearfix:after { clear: both; }
```

and the following is my html:

```html
<div id="sidebar1" class="sidebar fourcol first clearfix:after" role="complementary">

  <?php if ( is_active_sidebar( 'sidebar1' ) ) : ?>

    <?php dynamic_sidebar( 'sidebar1' ); ?>

  <?php else : ?>

    <!-- This content shows up if there are no widgets defined in the backend. -->

    <div class="alert help">
      <p><?php _e("Please activate some Widgets.", "bonestheme");  ?></p>
    </div>

  <?php endif; ?>

</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove `:after` from the class attribute in your HTML:

```
<div id="sidebar1" class="sidebar fourcol first clearfix" role="complementary">
```

---

**P.S.** Your SCSS is OK, but here's a more convenient way of accomplishing the same thing:

```css
.clearfix {
    zoom: 1;

    &:before, &:after {
        content: "";
        display: table;
    }
    &:after {
        clear: both;
    }
}
```

Comment: ok that works, my problem is the clear:both isn't being applied, when I add clear both in inspector to the div it stacks the div below the previous one, here is the site http://update.mrskitson.ca/ I would like the sidebar to stack below but clearfix isnt making it do so.

Comment: @AndersKitson - This is not what the clearfix is for. To make the sidebar stack just clear the sidebar itself: `.sidebar { clear: both }`

Comment: ok that works thanks, what is the purpose of clearfix? i dont quite understand it?

Comment: @AndersKitson - Check out [this article](http://devotepress.com/coding/css-clearfix-hack/).